# Rails 3 installation problem with RVM on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rvm

I'm trying to get Rails 3 installed in my fresh Mac OS X setup but I've got some problems.
I'm downloading RVM and installing Ruby 1.9.2 without troubles, but when I try to install Rails using:

```
gem install rails
```

I get:

```
Thomas@~ $ gem install rails
/Users/Thomas/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:28:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::ConfigFile (NameError)
from /Users/Thomas/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Thomas/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Thomas/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Thomas/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Thomas/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Thomas/./rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/gem:13:in `<main>'
```

I tried many things; I removed RVM, and reinstalled it, but I'm still getting this error.

What I find weird is that RVM is installed in `~HOME/rvm` and not in `~HOME/.rvm`.

When I stay with my original Ruby version, gem is recognized. Maybe should I create a link somewhere to link gem with different versions?

Comment: how did you install rvm? you can try installing rvm as root, for all users. as root execute `bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)`

Comment: Okay I just found the problem, I had to install MacPort first ...

Comment: MacPort has nothing to do with RVM or installing a Ruby with RVM - I have two Macs with RVM, multiple Rubies installed by it, and neither has MacPorts installed.

Answer (score 0):

When you install RVM, are you using the "Installation Methods" directions on the RVM [installation](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) page?

When you run `bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)` at the command-prompt, RVM will automatically create the `~/.rvm` directory for you.

Because you are seeing `rvm`, without the preceding `.`, I think you're somehow installing the system-wide version into your home directory. Are you installing using `sudo` or running as root? Neither is necessary when installing into your home directory as a single-user sandbox.

Installing as root, or using `sudo` changes the environment and ownership of the files, and can cause all sorts of evil little annoyances. When you take the easy path, of installing as yourself, it should go very easily.

I've installed RVM, and multiple Rubies on a good number of hosts, and the only times I've had problems were with locked down environments that couldn't actually see the necessary Ruby archives, or that didn't have curl or git installed, such as old versions of Centos.